# Visual Studio DTE - how to programmatically select multiple projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, envdte

I'm trying to create a little Visual Studio Extension, to do some batch project load and unloading. To do this, I have to select multiple projects at once and then call the `Project.ReloadProject` or `Project.UnloadProject` command. If I load or unload project after project, it's far too slow.

Here's my sample:

```
foreach (UIHierarchyItem item in solution.UIHierarchyItems)
{
    if (!filter.Projects.Contains(item.Name, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        item.Select(vsUISelectionType.vsUISelectionTypeSelect);
}

dte.ExecuteCommand("Project.UnloadProject", "");
```

The problem is, that I don't know, how to select multiple projects at once. When I'm doing the same task manually, I just hold the `ctrl` button and click at the projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select multiple projects, for the first project call:

```
item.Select(vsUISelectionType.vsUISelectionTypeSelect);
```

for subsequent projects call:

```
   if (!item.IsSelected)
       item.Select(vsUISelectionType.vsUISelectionTypeToggle);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't consider that, because in the documentation it says after you select a node using the toggle value it is the ONLY selected node.